# read in one row of csv file (based on input if i can) with DictReader, then format and write to new file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read in a csv file with many rows and columns; i would like to print one row, in a particular format, to a text file, and do some hashing on the values. SO far, i have been able to read in the file, parse thru it using DictReader, find the row i want using an IF statement and then print the keys and values. I cannot figure out how to format it to the format i want in the end ( Key = Value \n), and i cannot figure how to write to a file (much less in the format i want) using the value of 'row' obtained below. I've been trying for days and make a little progress but cannot get it to work. Here is what i got to work (with much detail left out of results):

---

```
>>>import csv

with open("C:\path_to_script\filename_Brief.csv") as infh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infh)
    for row in reader:
        if row['ALIAS'] == 'Y4K':
            print(row)
```

## result-output

{'Full_Name': 'Jack Flash', 'PHONE_NO': '555 555-1212', 'ALIAS': 'Y4K'}

---

I'd like to ask the user to input the Alias and then use that to determine row to print. I've done a ton of research but am new-ish to Python so am asking for help! i've used pyexcel, xlrd/xlwt, even thought I'd try pandas but too much to learn. I also got it to format the way i wanted in one test but then could not get the row selection to work--in other words, it prints all the records rather than the row i want. Have 30 Firefox tabs open trying to find an answer! Thanks in advance!

Comment: my tabs/indents are all off. I do have them correct in IDLE.

Comment: How, exactly, do you want the row shown formatted in the output file?

Comment: For example: Full Name = Jack Flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may at least be close to what you want (I think):

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\path_to_script\filename_Brief.csv') as infh, \
     open('new_file.txt', 'wt') as outfh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infh)
    for row in reader:
        if row['ALIAS'] == 'Y4K':
             outfh.write('Full_Name = {Full_Name}\n'
                         'PHONE_NO = {PHONE_NO}\n'
                         'ALIAS = {ALIAS}\n'.format(**row))
```

This would write 3 lines formatted like this into the output file for every matching`row`:

```
Full_Name = Jack Flash 
PHONE_NO = 555 555-1212
ALIAS = Y4K
```

BTW, the `**row`notation means basically "take all the entries in the specified dictionary and turn them into keyword arguments for this function call". The `{keyword}` syntax in the format string refers to any keyword arguments that will be passed to the `str.format()` method.

Comment: i am liking this! i  want it to be Full_Name = Jack Flash \n PHONE_NO = 555-555-1212, etc. all on their own lines. I will look up that format--i don't understand (**row)

Comment: it worked perfectly; now i just need to format and hash values. thank you!

Comment: thank you for the explanation too. That explains why i kept getting  not defined errors when i just tried to write it using (key, record[key]). and various other ways i tried.

Comment: To do it that way you would have needed something like `'Full_Name = {}\nPHONE_NO = {}\nALIAS = {}\n'.format(row['Full_Name'], row['PHONE_NO'], row['ALIAS']))` to accomplish the same thing. See the [_Format String Syntax_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) section in the online documentation. Also note the `r` prefix I added to your `'C:\path_to_script\filename_Brief.csv`' file path string because of the backslashes.

Comment: An advantage to passing the arguments explicitly rather than converting them all to keyword arguments with the `**` is when they wouldn't all be valid Python identifiers. This might be required to handle cases were the keys are things like `row['Full Name']`, `row['!@$%^&*']`, or `row[42]`.